# How to trace all dependencies in SQL server (SSMS)

Tags: sql, reference, dependencies, ssms

I need to map all SQL server data, obtaining all tables, views and relations between them.
It was easy to recover via query all tables and views in SQL server(s), but now I need to query SQL to trace all relations between views and tables (and so, also between views and other views), to see all relations between these objects.

Any idea?

I tried lots of different sys tables; some of them can recover only dependencies within the same db.
The table to trace cross-db (and cross server?!) dependencies should be sys.sql_expression_dependencies , but it can't recover some dependencies (<<The sys.sql_expression_dependencies catalog view contains information about the dependencies of objects within a database, including cross-database and cross-server dependencies. However, it does not include all types of dependencies. For example, if an object references another object using dynamic SQL or if an object references a temporary table or table variable, its dependencies might not be recorded in this catalog view.>>)

I think all dependencies are captured by SSMS, as you can see them manually, but I don't know how to extract them via query.

Comment: `sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities(),  sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities()`

Comment: Dynamic SQL isn't going to appear, no, because the object is *not* dependant; the dynamic statement is and that is **not** an object. What object(s) would you expect the statement to be dependant on, when the dynamic statement, and thus the objects it references, are dynamic...? You won't know until you run the query.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve information about the relationships between tables, views, and other database objects in SQL Server, you can query the system catalog views.

```
SELECT 
    obj.name AS object_name,
    obj.type_desc AS object_type,
    CASE 
        WHEN obj.type = 'V' THEN dep.referenced_entity_name
        WHEN obj.type = 'F' THEN fk.referenced_object_id
        ELSE NULL
    END AS referenced_object_name,
    CASE 
        WHEN obj.type = 'V' THEN 'View'
        WHEN obj.type = 'F' THEN 'Foreign Key'
        ELSE NULL
    END AS referenced_object_type
FROM 
    sys.objects AS obj
LEFT JOIN 
    sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS dep ON obj.object_id = dep.referencing_id
LEFT JOIN 
    sys.foreign_keys AS fk ON obj.object_id = fk.parent_object_id
WHERE 
    obj.type IN ('V', 'F')
ORDER BY 
    obj.name;
```

Comment: this way I get only one record, while there are thousands of views with their dependencies.